# Internal Server Error (gack) Submit for Approval - VF Email Templates

Tags: approval-process, gack

**Use Case:**

- Approval Process on custom object
- Approval Assignment Email Template: Visualforce

User clicks Submit for Approval, SFDC responds with `Internal Server Error`.

*Question will be self-answered as a service to the community.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately, [SFDC Help had the clue](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000233284&language=en_US), pointing me to an issue with the VF email template

1. Prior to bug report, Submit for Approval was working fine
2. VF template had markup like below:

   ```
    <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Foo__c.fields.Industry__c.Label}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Industry__c}"/>
   ```

Developer then deleted field `Foo.Industry__c`. **SFDC does not tell you that the field is being used in a VF Email template in the way above - no warning**.

When Submit for Approval is then clicked, the gack ensues because, after `Industry__c` was deleted, the VF markup looks like the below:

```
     <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Foo__c.fields.00NR0000001Zu8o.Label}"/>
     <apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.00NR0000001Zu8o}"/>
```

where `00NR0000001Zu8o` is the id of the deleted field

Solution is to fix the VF email template and remove the offending, deleted field.